Tikz graph drawing help, Hertzsprung–Russell diagram
I am trying to draw a Hertzsprung–Russell diagram. Not a completely accurate diagram with data. just a diagram that looks a bit like the one insert.
I can get it a bit right but I am having trouble with getting it to look like a scatter plot- without using data.
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadings, decorations.pathmorphing}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{loglogaxis}[
                xlabel={Temperature (K)},
                ylabel={$L/L_\odot$},
                xmin=2000, xmax=40000,
                ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e6,
                xtick={2000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 40000},
                xticklabels={2000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 40000},
                ytick={1e-4, 1e-2, 1, 1e2, 1e4, 1e6},
                x dir=reverse, % Reverse the x-axis for Temperature
                grid=both,
                minor tick num=5,
                major grid style={black!50},
                minor grid style={gray!25},
                xticklabel style={anchor=north east, rotate=45}, % Slant the labels
                enlargelimits={0.1}, % Adds 10% extra space
                ]
    
                % White dwarfs region with a fuzzy oval
                \shade[inner color=orange!80!gray, opacity=0.8]    
                            (12000, 1e-2) ellipse [x radius=1.7cm, y radius=0.4cm, rotate=-20]; % Inner bright part
                \shade[outer color=orange!80!white, opacity=0.8] 
                    (12000, 1e-2) ellipse [x radius=1.75cm, y radius=0.5cm, rotate=-20]; % Outer fuzzy part
                   
                % Giants region with a fuzzy oval
                \shade[inner color=orange!80!gray, opacity=0.8]    
                            (4000, 1.5e2) ellipse [x radius=0.6cm, y radius=0.3cm, rotate=45]; % Inner bright part
                \shade[outer color=orange!80!white, opacity=0.4] 
                    (4000, 1.5e2) ellipse [x radius=0.65cm, y radius=0.4cm, rotate=45]; % Outer fuzzy part
                 
                 % Supergiants region (banana shape) from 30,000 K to 3,000 K
                 \shade[inner color=orange!80!gray, outer color=orange!10!white, opacity=0.4] 
                 (30000, 1e6) -- % Start point at (30,000 K, 10^4 L/L⊙)
                 plot[smooth, tension=1] coordinates {
                     (20000, 5e4)  % Middle point at (20,000 K, 5,000 L/L⊙)
                     (10000, 1e4)  % Next curve point at (10,000 K, 3,000 L/L⊙)
                     (5000, 1e4)   % Lower point at (5,000 K, 1,000 L/L⊙)
                     (3000, 5e6)   % End point at (3,000 K, 500 L/L⊙)
                 } to[out=-40, in=140] (3500, 1e6) -- 
                 plot[smooth cycle, tension=1] coordinates { 
                      (5000,1e5)
                     (30000, 7e4)
                 };  % Complete the banana shape
    
            \end{loglogaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Hertzsprung-Russell Diagram with Supergiants Region (Banana Shape)}
    \end{figure}
    
    \end{document}

Current:

Intended:


Here is one way to do it. Basic steps:

draw, using plain Tikz, a closed polygon, using axis cs: coordinates
draw it outside the plot frame (so it clips)
use e.g. to[in=,out=] to replace the normal straight lines from --
use some style to change colors

Style, at beginning of tikzpicture:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ban/.style={fill=orange!80, draw=none},
    ]

4th region; for a comparision you may want to revert to --:
             % ~~~ the 4th region ~~~~~~~~~~~~
             \draw[ban]     
                    (axis cs:50000,7e5) to[out=-45,in=93] 
                    (axis cs:3000, 1e-5) --
                    (axis cs:2200,1e-5) to[out=95,in=-45] 
                    (axis cs:50000, 3e6) -- cycle;

        \end{loglogaxis}

Here using 4 points and two to-statements seem to be sufficient. If not, change angles and/or add more points.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ban/.style={fill=orange!80, draw=none},
    ]
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            xlabel={Temperature (K)},
            ylabel={$L/L_\odot$},
            xmin=2000, xmax=40000,
            ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e6,
            xtick={2000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 40000},
            xticklabels={2000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 40000},
            ytick={1e-4, 1e-2, 1, 1e2, 1e4, 1e6},
            x dir=reverse, % Reverse the x-axis for Temperature
            grid=both,
            minor tick num=5,
            major grid style={black!50},
            minor grid style={gray!25},
            xticklabel style={anchor=north east, rotate=45}, % Slant the labels
            enlargelimits={0.05}, % //Adds 10% extra space
            ]

            % White dwarfs region with a fuzzy oval
            \shade[inner color=orange!80!gray, opacity=0.8]    
                        (12000, 1e-2) ellipse [x radius=1.7cm, y radius=0.4cm, rotate=-20]; % Inner bright part
            \shade[outer color=orange!80!white, opacity=0.8] 
                (12000, 1e-2) ellipse [x radius=1.75cm, y radius=0.5cm, rotate=-20]; % Outer fuzzy part
               
            % Giants region with a fuzzy oval
            \shade[inner color=orange!80!gray, opacity=0.8]    
                        (4000, 1.5e2) ellipse [x radius=0.6cm, y radius=0.3cm, rotate=45]; % Inner bright part
            \shade[outer color=orange!80!white, opacity=0.4] 
                (4000, 1.5e2) ellipse [x radius=0.65cm, y radius=0.4cm, rotate=45]; % Outer fuzzy part
             
             % Supergiants region (banana shape) from 30,000 K to 3,000 K
             \shade[inner color=orange!80!gray, outer color=orange!10!white, opacity=0.4] 
             (30000, 1e6) -- % Start point at (30,000 K, 10^4 L/L⊙)
             plot[smooth, tension=1] coordinates {
                 (20000, 5e4)  % Middle point at (20,000 K, 5,000 L/L⊙)
                 (10000, 1e4)  % Next curve point at (10,000 K, 3,000 L/L⊙)
                 (5000, 1e4)   % Lower point at (5,000 K, 1,000 L/L⊙)
                 (3000, 5e6)   % End point at (3,000 K, 500 L/L⊙)
             } to[out=-40, in=140] (3500, 1e6) -- 
             plot[smooth cycle, tension=1] coordinates { 
                  (5000,1e5)
                 (30000, 7e4)
             };  % Complete the banana shape
             
             % ~~~ the 4th region ~~~~~~~~~~~~
             \draw[ban]     
                    (axis cs:50000,7e5) to[out=-45,in=93] 
                    (axis cs:3000, 1e-5) --
                    (axis cs:2200,1e-5) to[out=95,in=-45] 
                    (axis cs:50000, 3e6) -- cycle;

        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Hertzsprung-Russell Diagram with Supergiants Region (Banana Shape)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


P.S.: When you replace \draw by \shadedraw you can replicate your coloration. You can enter formatting options directly, as shown, or more systematically at the beginning, see previous code.
             % ~~~ the 4th region ~~~~~~~~~~~~
       %      \draw[ban]    
              \shadedraw[
                inner color=orange!80!gray, 
                outer color=orange!30!white, 
                opacity=0.8,
                draw=none
              ]            
                    (axis cs:50000,7e5) to[out=-45,in=93] 
                    (axis cs:3000, 1e-5) --
                    (axis cs:2200,1e-5) to[out=95,in=-45] 
                    (axis cs:50000, 3e6) -- cycle;

        \end{loglogaxis}


